# how to change perf_event_open max sample rate

Tags: linux, perf

I'm using perf_event_open to get samples. I try to get everyone hit of point. But perf_event_open is not fast enough. I try to change the sample rate using below command:

```
echo 10000000 > /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_max_sample_rate
```

But it looks like the value I set was too large. After running my code, perf_event_max_sample_rate is change back to a lower value such as 12500. And when I try to change bigger value,for example 20000000,50000000 and so on, the sample speed is not increased as value I changed to. Is there any way to change perf_event_open sample speed more faster?

Comment: This is not exactly a programming question and should be asked over at https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5):

This is a mechanism to limit the overhead caused by perf. You can disable it by setting

```
sysctl -w kernel.perf_cpu_time_max_percent=0
```

Use at your own risk - the system may stop to respond.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt

> perf_cpu_time_max_percent:
>
> Hints to the kernel how much CPU time it should be allowed to use to
>   handle perf sampling events.  If the perf subsystem is informed that
>   its samples are exceeding this limit, it will drop its sampling
>   frequency to attempt to reduce its CPU usage.
>
> Some perf sampling happens in NMIs.  If these samples unexpectedly
>   take too long to execute, the NMIs can become stacked up next to each
>   other so much that nothing else is allowed to execute.
>
> 0: disable the mechanism.  Do not monitor or correct perf's
>   sampling rate no matter how CPU time it takes.
>
> 1-100: attempt to throttle perf's sample rate to this    percentage of
>   CPU.  Note: the kernel calculates an    "expected" length of each
>   sample event.  100 here means    100% of that expected length.  Even
>   if this is set to    100, you may still see sample throttling if this 
>   length is exceeded.  Set to 0 if you truly do not care    how much CPU
>   is consumed.

Answer (score 4):

It is really not possible to increase the `perf_event_max_sample_rate` beyond a certain value.

I have tried increasing it to above `100,000` , say for example something like a `200,000` or something more. Every time I did this, the max sample rate always came down to something like **146,500 samples/sec** or less. If I recall correctly, this was the maximum I could achieve (i.e. **146,500 samples/sec**). This would of course, depend on the kind of machine you are using and the CPU frequencies etc. I was working on an **Intel Xeon v-5 Broadwell CPU**.

**Zulan** makes a good point. To make your understanding clearer, the perf sample collection is based on interrupts. Every time the sampling counter overflows, `perf` would raise an NM(non-maskable) interrupt. This interrupt meanwhile will calculate the time it takes to actually handle the whole interrupt process. You can see this in the below kernel code :-

[perf_event_nmi_handler](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.15/source/arch/x86/events/core.c#L1509)

Now once it has calculated the time for handling the interrupt, it calls another function (in which it passes the interrupt handling time as a parameter) where it tries to examine and compare the current `perf_event_max_sample_rate` with the time it takes to handle the interrupt. If it finds that the interrupt is taking a long enough time and at the same time, the samples are being generated very frequently, the CPU will obviously not be able to keep up as interrupt work starts getting queued up and you will observe some amount of `CPU throttling`. If you look at the below function, there will always be an attempt to reduce the sample

Read the below function to understand :-

[perf_event_sample_took](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.15/source/kernel/events/core.c#L504)

Of course, as Zulan suggested, you can try making it 0, but you would get the same maximum number of samples from `perf` and further hurt the CPU, it is not possible to increase the maximum unless you figure out other means (like tweaking the buffer if possible).

Comment: Maybe I should have made it more clear. Of course setting that value to a large number doesn't mean it's practically achievable. It just means that it's not throttled by the kernel any longer. A value of `perf_cpu_time_max_percent=0` (or 100) will cause `perf_sample_allowed_ns` to be set to 0 and `perf_event_sample_took` won't do anything.