# Using perf to get events counts depending on the occurrence of other events

Tags: linux, profiling, performancecounter, perf

Is there any possible way on which I can get the value of event counters depending on the occurrence of other events?
For example: if I want to know the value of performance counters each time a specific counter reach a specific value.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with `perf_event_open`, but AFAIK not directly with the current version of `perf record`.

> I want to know the value of performance counters each time a specific counter reach a specific value.

Use a group of events, the *"specific counter"* is the group leader. For this event you set:

```
struct perf_event_attr leader;
leader.sample_type = PERF_SAMPLE_TIME | PERF_SAMPLE_READ;
leader.sample_period = specific_value;
// set type/config accordingly
leader.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP;
group_fd = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &leader, tid, cpu, -1, 0);
...

struct perf_event_attr other;
other.sample_period = 0; // doesn't trigger overflows
// set type/config accordingly
syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &other, tid, cpu, group_fd, 0);

// do the mmap dance, ioctl etc. with the fd you get for the leader
// read values from both leader and other counters in your mmap buffer.
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great or complete answer, but it's too big for a comment.

---

IDK if that's possible with the `perf` utility itself, but in theory yes you could get that for legacy events that trigger an interrupt every time their counter overflows (at a programmable overflow count; this is how event sampling granularity works).  You can then read the values from the counters for other events.  Probably using the same API that `perf` does, you could write code that does this from user-space.

But on x86 [for PEBS (precise events)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218275/good-resources-on-how-to-program-pebs-precise-event-based-sampling-counters), you probably can't, because counter overflows put an event in a buffer instead of triggering an interrupt right then where you could do arbitrary other things.  So if the event you want to use is only available as a precise event, you will need a different solution to your ultimate problem.

(Low level bonus reading about interrupts / exceptions in general, including performance events vs. PEBS: [When an interrupt occurs, what happens to instructions in the pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902132/when-an-interrupt-occurs-what-happens-to-instructions-in-the-pipeline))

---

You probably want to know something about how events are correlated with each other.  Wanting to sample other events when one overflows may be an X-Y problem, if you can't implement it easily.

`perf record --timestamp` will put a timestamp on each event.  This may give you the raw data you need to learn what you want to know.  [Collecting the data for a partiulcar process from PMU for every 1 milli second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762198/collecting-the-data-for-a-partiulcar-process-from-pmu-for-every-1-milli-second) is related, and suggests using `perf script` to do something with the results of `perf record --all-cpus --timestamp`.